# Read Image present in Django Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

The code of the model is as follows

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to='Files')
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to read the file (image or video).
Let's say its an image. I want to read this image in an array format.

I tried with the following code but i just get the file name and not a image matrix

```
img = Post.objects.all()[0].file
print(img)


OR
print(np.array(img))
```

Output is : car-1.jpg

Expected output : 2d Array

Answer (score 1):

by default django store file or image path.. not a file

so you should get your file path + your url and use for example **wget lib** to get it after that you can use it

example:

```
import cv2, wget
image_url = 'server_url + link_from_query'
filename = wget.download(image_url)
np_image = cv2.imread(filename)
```